# How to Copy lines containing a specific text from one file to another file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

Copy all lines from file1 that contain "Data,10", "Data,11", "Data,12", or "Data,13" into a file2. The lines in the solution should be in the same order as they appear in the file1 file.

This is my code:

```
awk '/Data:\[1310\]/p' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What *does* happen when you run it?

Comment: Creating a good sample input and expected output would help a lot. Apart from things already mentioned in the answer so far, you have tried `:` in the code but it is `,` in the description.

Comment: @KensukeSuzuki : In addition to what Sundeep said, you have backslashes in your pattern which are not present in your sample data, and you have a spurious `p` character after the pattern, which I don't understand either.

Answer (score 3):

You look like you're confusing `awk` and `sed`. They're different tools with different syntaxes (Though similar in this case since it's mostly a regular expression problem); you can't mix or match. Plus you shouldn't be escaping the brackets in the regular expression unless you want to match them as literal characters....

A few ways using common tools:

With `sed`: `sed -n '/Data,1[0-3]/p' file1.txt > file1.txt`

With `awk`: `awk '/Data,1[0-3]/' file1.txt > file2.txt`

With `grep`: `grep 'Data,1[0-3]' file1.txt > file2.txt`

Comment: I'd use the last one; sed and awk are overkill for this, fwiw.